# can I solve MySQL query without using join?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to solve this mysql question.
 Q.) employee(employee-name, street, city)
     works(employee-name, company-name, salary)
     company(company-name, city)
     manages(employee-name, manager-name)

where employee, works, company, manages are tables of mysql.
and name in braces are columns for respective tables.
My question is..
How to find all employees in the database who live in the same cities and on the same streets as do their managers?

Managers are also employees. So their address is also stored into employee table.

so far I have tried this query and many other queries..

```
select employee.employee_name 
from employee,works,company,manages 
where employee.employee_name=manages.employee_name 
and employee.street in 
    (select employee.street 
     from employee,manages 
     where manages.manager_name=employee.employee_name);
```

Comment: What have *you* tried so far?

Comment: This isn't a forum for helping you with your homework (and certainly not for DOING your homework), but rather for helping resolve technical issues.

Comment: Now that I look back to my question after more than 3 years, I certainly don't believe the height of my own stupidity! Sorry Guys for asking such a needless question. Now can anyone help me how to delete this? I seem to can't find way around that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the name is a unique identifier:

```
SELECT e.employee_name
FROM   employee e
JOIN   manages em ON e.employee_name = em.employee_name
JOIN   employee m ON em.manager_name = m.employee_name AND 
                     e.city = m.city AND
                     e.street = m.street
```

Comment: Shows this error:
Unknown column 'e.manager_name' in 'on clause'

Comment: @DazzleR oops, should have been `em.mamabger_name` - fixed.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Or give some sample data to work with (or better yet, an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com))?

Comment: My logical answer and answer from this query shows different answers. And where can I upload my .sql file of this database so u can check?

Comment: @DazzleR either paste it in the question itself, or share on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: this is url for manages table : http://d.pr/f/RHze
this is url for employee table: http://d.pr/f/dSDp